# Auto refresh table didn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table, refresh

I want to refresh my table every 5 seconds..

Now I'm using this **code**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#content').load('refresh_data_dapur.php');
        setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
    }
</script>
```

**refresh_data_dapur.php**

```
$sql = "select t.no_meja, d.nama_menu,d.jumlah,t.status from detail_transaksi d join transaksi t on(d.id_transaksi=t.id_transaksi) where t.status ='pending' and d.status_menu = 'pending'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
                    echo '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1">';
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo    '<th>No Meja</th>';
                    echo    '<th>Nama Menu</th>';
                    echo    '<th>Jumlah</th>';      
                    echo    '<th>Status</th>';      
                    echo '</tr>';
                    while($detail_transaksi = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                    echo    '<tr>';
                    echo    '<td>';
                    echo    $detail_transaksi['no_meja'];
                    echo'</td>';
                    echo    '<td>';
                    echo $detail_transaksi['nama_menu'];
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo    '<td>';
                    echo $detail_transaksi['jumlah'];
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo    '<td>';
                    echo $detail_transaksi['status'];
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo  '</tr>';
                    }
```

in my **html** :

```
<div id="content">

</div>
```

When I try to load the page, it doesn't show anything...

When in the html I modify into this code, it shows the data but the table still isn't refreshing...

```
<div id="content">
    <?php include("refresh_data_dapur.php");?>
 </div>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try replacing `setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);` with `setTimeout(arguments.callee, 5000);`

Comment: Since when your problem is PHP related?

Comment: since the page i call is PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is fine here. but you are using `setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);`. It will run the `refreshTable` function once after 5 seconds of page load. You should be using

```
setInterval(refreshTable, 5000);
```

instead. That will run every five second and keep it outside and after `refreshTable` function because you are using it in setTimeout before it is declared. That might be the cause.

Comment: i already change the code to 'setInterval(refreshTable, 5000);' but still the table didn't refreshing..

Comment: Check the console if there is any error or in chrome console under network tab you can see the current status of your xhr request.

Comment: i forgot to link the '<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>'.it works now..thanks..

Comment: hey..can you take a look at my website ? [link](http://www.nervousme.vacau.com/show_dapur.html) .the table is doing something odd, its refresh the table and go back to previous data..i wonder whats wrong with this page or something wrong with the server?

Comment: I gave it a look but it's working fine. Not only table but it's also refreshing form below it.